# Use only a single Geany instance under Windows

Tags: geany

I'm running Geany 1.34.1 under Windows 10. Whenever I click a text file on Windows Explorer Geany opens the file in a new instance.

How can I configure Geany so that it opens all files in a single instance only?

Answer (score 0):

According to [a section of the Geany documentation](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#opening-files-from-the-command-line-in-a-running-instance), the behavior you want should occur unless Geany is started with the appropriate command line option. From the [table of command line options](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#command-line-options), that would be either `-i` or `--new-instance`.

Check your file type association for text files and delete either of those command line options if they're there.

If no options are found, you might check your [Geany configuration file](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#configuration-files) to see if there's something related to starting a new instance. If so, you can try deleting the related stuff and see what happens. ***Be sure to make a backup copy of the configuration file before editing it so you can recover in case something goes terribly wrong.***

If no options are found anywhere, then it may be a bug in the Windows version of Geany.

Comment: Thanks. I found this bug report: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/2101. It seems to be a bug with the Windows version indeed.